# Добавление возможности изменение вариантов товара Woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как мне сделать возможность изменение вариативного товара в корзине http://prntscr.com/hb7e92. Пример на скриншоте. Может, есть плагин?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

[Woocommerce custom product data fields](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-product-data-fields/)

[Woocommerce custom product fields](http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/)